# Finished activity automatically reopens

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-finish

I have a problem in a very simple application.

I have a main activity, and on button click I open a second activity:

```
newEntryButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSpendingActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When I close this activity (for example by tapping the back button) or by calling `finish()` the view loads once again. It only closes if I tap the back button again. What may be the cause of this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you close `MainActivity`, `MainActivity` opens again?

Comment: No.. when I close NewSpendingActivitiy, NewSpendingActivity opens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you're using an `OnTouchListener`, which triggers on press, move and release. Try using an `OnClickListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should not give you problems:

```
newEntryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewSpendingActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

        }
    });
```